# dynamically creating text boxes after loop through javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a javascript that sends some info to through an ajax request to the server and receives some data as Questions and their's ID's as a json array.

This is what the response json array i receive from the server looks like:

```
   [
     {
      "ID":"1",
      "question":"Write a function called addNum. "
        },
     {
      "ID":"3",
      "question":"Write a function called sumDouble "
      }
    ]
```

And this is javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#input_qnumber").submit(function() {

    var questions = $('#questions').attr('value'); // written question
    var quizname = $('#quizname').attr('value');

    if (questions) { // values are not empty
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://xxxx",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "application/json",
            data: 'questions='+questions+'&quizname='+quizname,

            success: function (data) 
            {
                var JSONObject = JSON.parse(data); 

                for (var key in JSONObject) {
                    if (JSONObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        console.log(JSONObject[key]["ID"] + ", " + JSONObject[key]["question"]);
                    }
                }



            }

        });
    }
    else {
        $('div#createquizresp').text("Enter question ID's separated by a comma to be included in the quiz");
        $('div#createquizresp').addClass("error");
    } // else
    $('div#createquizresp').fadeIn();
    return false;
});
});
```

As you see, I can parse the response json into a javascript object array, loop through it and dump the contents in console. What I would like though would be to create textarea element, give its id attribute the 'ID' key from my array and label it with the corresponding question key from the array. After this I can just append the element to a div inside my html. But I am not really sure how to do it or if its even possible. Please HALP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want also a label element;

```
for (var key in JSONObject) {
    if (JSONObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        $('<label>')
            .attr('for', JSONObject[key]["ID"])
            .html(JSONObject[key]["question"])
            .appendTo('wherever_you_want');
        $('<textarea>')
            .attr('id', JSONObject[key]["ID"])
            .appendTo('wherever_you_want');
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect just one question though, is there a way to create a form first through this and append that to div and then just append all these elements inside that form to that form.

Answer (score 0):

create dynamic elements input and label and then append these elements to the parent div or to the body what ever suits your requirement.

DEMO :https://jsfiddle.net/ew4mqhow/3/

```
<div id ="display"></div>

<script>
var textbox = document.createElement('input');
textbox.setAttribute("id", JSONObject[key]["ID"]);
var labell = document.createElement('label');
labell.setAttribute("for",JSONObject[key]["question"]);
labell.innerHTML = JSONObject[key]["question"];

document.getElementById('display').appendChild(textbox);
document.getElementById('display').appendChild(labell);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer by keune is perfect. One suggestion, tho - do add a prefix to foreign ID's. Just to be on safe side on case You'll assign ID's to other types of elements (ie. answers), too.

```
for (var key in JSONObject) {
    if (JSONObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        $('#quizquestions')
            .append($('<label>')
                .attr('for', 'Q' + JSONObject[key]["ID"])
                .html(JSONObject[key]["question"]))
            .append($('<textarea>')
                .attr('id', 'Q' + JSONObject[key]["ID"]))
    }
}
```